Utilizing a three (or two) variable linear system of equations, how can I solve a word problem involving combinations of items?
I would have been more specific in my question but the field doesn't allow for all the characters, so I will post the actual question here.
"In the 2016 Summer Olympics, China, the United States, and Great Britain won a combined total of 258 medals. China won 51 fewer medals than the United States. Great Britain won 54 fewer medals than the United States. How many medals did each country win?"
I seem to be making a simple mistake. I have come across a site that has a solution, but it involves substitution of one or more of the equations, whereas I am using elimination of variable as my method. I am not sure if I must use substitution.
I have used the variables of "C" for China, "G" for Great Britain and "U" for the USA.
Am I making a mistake in my premise of using three variables instead of two? I know I must have at least two variables to solve the problem the way the book wants me to solve it.
I have completed a trig course so I have learned algebra already. I am reviewing algebra and these word problems give me a loop even though I can do the calculations if I have the proper equations.
Thanks for your reading this lengthy post and for any answers you may provide.


China won 51 fewer medals than the United States:
C=U−51

Great Britain won 54 fewer medals than the United States:
G=U−54

The total number of medals they won combined is 258:
C+U+G=258


Now, you have a system of three equations with three variables. You can solve this system using the method of your choice, whether it's elimination, substitution, or any other algebraic method.
The easiest way to do this would probably be by substitution: Replace the variables in the third equation with the first and second equation:
(U−51)+U+(U−54)=258

Now you have only one variable and one equation.
Let me know if you need further help!

That's basically along the lines of what I have tried but I thought I was making a mistake in the process because it is a fairly simple solution. I thought that the book wanted me to do something more complicated, but as you have shown, I was wrong to make that assumption. Thanks for your help. I greatly appreciate it.

Welcome! Happy to help!

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
